# How do I cross reference automatically numbered figures in R Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, cross-reference

I am writing a relatively long HTML ebook, with a large number of pictures that are automatically numbered via html_document2. I insert figures using the following code.

```
{r, echo=FALSE, out.width="75%", fig.align = "center", fig.cap="My caption."}
knitr::include_graphics("..../Picture1.png")
```

In the text, I want to refer to the figure. For example, something like **(Figure 2.2)**. I tried using the following format, and variations of it, but it did not generate a cross-reference. Can anyone clarify how I do this?

```
\ref{fig:My caption.}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References in `bookdown` are different from LaTex.  First, you need to name the code chunk that has the figure, and the name should just have letters and digits in it, no spaces or other special characters.  Then the syntax for the reference is `\@ref(fig:name)`.  (Note it uses round parens, not braces!)  For your example, this should work:

````
```{r Figure1, echo=FALSE, out.width="75%", fig.align = "center", fig.cap="My caption."}
knitr::include_graphics("..../Picture1.png")
```

That was Figure \@ref(fig:Figure1).
````

Comment: That worked great, thanks! It's a pain that a separate name is needed for every image. I do observe that it only cross-references the figure number (i.e. "2.1" rather than "Figure 2.1"). Is there a way to make it do that?

Comment: I imagine you could use some inline R code and write `r ref(Figure1)` to do whatever you wanted, though there might be issues with escaping the special chars in the `\@ref`.  Re the naming:  how else could the system know which figure you were referring to, except by using the name?